# mat-select Not Working Properly

Tags: angular, angular-material2

The `mat-select` element is acting funny. See below.

**Code**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" #NameInput>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-select placeholder="How Many?">
    <mat-option>One</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Two</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Three</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Four</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Five</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Results**

[image: mat-select element acting weird]

Wrapping the `mat-select` in a `mat-form-field` gives me the following error:

> mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Did you forget to
>   add matInput to the native input or textarea element?

However, including an `input` with `matInput` shows both the `input` and the `mat-select` together, making it look weird. Any way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot to import MatSelectModule in my `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 10):

The message says that your select must be in a mat-form-field, not in the same mat-form-field as your input. Try this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" #NameInput>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="How Many?">
        <mat-option>One</mat-option>
        <mat-option>Two</mat-option>
        <mat-option>Three</mat-option>
        <mat-option>Four</mat-option>
        <mat-option>Five</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the doc that's how they do: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Comment: As I mentioned at the bottom of my post, adding a mat-form-field gives me the error.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to import MatSelectModule in my app.module.ts :p

Answer (score 2):

I mistakenly put place**H**older [in camelCase] instead of `placeholder` and it just ignored this!!!

It was very hard to find! but once I changed to `placeholder` I was able to see it. Just wanted to share in case you may also have run into..